# How to set selected item in select list per spring mvc3 using boostrap select?

Tags: java, html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have the following query params:

```
http://localhost:8085/myPage?selectListId=2
```

I have peeled that "selectListId" param from the query string in my GET method and I want to set the selected item in my drop down list to that index value.

I'm using bootstrap so not sure if that matters.  The list is populated from a viewModel that I pass in from my spring mvc3 controller.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="myController/indexSubmit" method="post">
    <select name="selectList" class="form-control" placeholder=".input-medium" height>
        <c:forEach items="${viewModel.getlistitems()}" var="item" varStatus="count"> 
            <option value="${count.index}">${item }</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Submit</button>   
</form>
```

How can I set this value (not using javascript preferably)?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to loop through the list elements of a list you added to the `Model` in your controller?

Comment: Hi...No, I have that part...the list is populated just fine. However, on postback I stored the selected item in the query param...redirect back to the main page with the list drop down ... but want to set the drop down list with that item index as selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `id` like that is a bad idea because it's not a true identifier, it's just the current index. For the answer's sake, given a controller method that handles your form submission

```
@RequestMapping(/* some mapping */
public String saveSelection(@RequestParam("selectList") String selectListId, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("selectListId", selectList);
    return "form"; // whatever it is
}
```

you compare the current index to the index in the request attributes and set it `selected` if they match

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="myController/indexSubmit" method="post">
    <select name="selectList" class="form-control" placeholder=".input-medium" height>
        <c:forEach items="${viewModel.getlistitems()}" var="item" varStatus="count"> 
            <option value="${count.index}"  ${not empty selectListId && selectListId == count.index ? 'selected' : ''} >${item }</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Submit</button>   
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked the first try!  Thanks again!